# Bounds on $\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

It's simple. What are the bounds on $\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}$ as $a,b,c>0$. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I need bound that can actually be touched i.e. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha\leq\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\leq\beta$

Comment: What makes you think the lowest upper bound and the greatest lower bound must be achievable by some particular values of $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a,\,b,\,c$ are positive real numbers then the answer is $2.$

Indeed, we have
$$\frac{c+a}{a+b+c}-\frac{a}{a+b}=\frac{bc}{(a+b)(a+b+c)} \geqslant 0,$$
so
$$\frac{a}{a+b} \leqslant \frac{c+a}{a+b+c},$$
therefore
$$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a} \leqslant \frac{(c+a)+(a+b)+(b+c)}{a+b+c}=2.$$
In addition, from
$$\frac{a}{a+b}>\frac{a}{a+b+c},$$
we get
$$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}>1.$$

Comment: A lower bound is $1,$ see updated proof.

Comment: Can you please find a bounds which can be touched? I will have to edit the statement. Anyhow, thank you.

Comment: What about the negative reals?

Comment: I am so so so sorry, I forgot to say those are greater than 0

Comment: By looking at the values of the expression for $a=1,b=N,c=N^2$ as $N\to \infty$, and on the other hand looking at the values of the expression for $a=N^2,b=N,c=1$, it appears that in fact 1 is the inf of the image and 2 is the sup of the image of $f(a,b,c) = \frac{a}{a+b} + \frac{b}{b+c} + \frac{c}{c+a}$ on $(\mathbb{R}^+)^3$.  (And shouldn't it be easy to change the proof to show $f(a,b,c) < 2$ always?)

Comment: You are right, but I do not want <. I need < or equal. Of course as a,b,c tend to some values to function tends to 1 or 2, but those cannot be reached. This would imply that (for the lower bound) 2 of the numbers are 0, leading in a case of absurdity regarding the division by 0 and (for the upper bound) all 3 numbers are 0, again being absurd! Are there no well defined reachable bounds? I mean, do the reachable bounds get infinitely close to 1 and 2 respectively?

Comment: Bumping (hope it is not against the rules)

Answer (score 1):

There are no well defined bounds.

Let $S$ denote the given expression. Note first that
$$S > \frac{a}{a+b+c}+\frac{b}{a+b+c}+\frac{c}{a+b+c}=1.$$
On the other hand, with $a=1$, $c=\varepsilon$ and $b=\varepsilon^2$ we have
$$S=\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon^2} + \frac{2\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} \to 1$$
as $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$. Thus the largest lower bound for $S$ is $1$.
For an upper bound, assume wlog that $a \leq b,c$. Then
$$S \leq \frac{a}{a+b} + \frac{b}{b+a}+\frac{c}{c+a} < 2.$$
With $a=1$, $b=\varepsilon$ and $c=\varepsilon^2$ we have
$$S = \frac{2}{1+\varepsilon} + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{1+\varepsilon^2} \to 2$$
as $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$. Hence the smallest upper bound for $S$ is $2$.